# Issues with Python dependencies - requests, requests_cache

Tags: python, python-requests

Any idea what package I am missing.

```
Python:

#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests 
import requests_cache

Error:
/bin/requests_cache/backends/init.py", line 54, in create_backend
_backend_dependencies[backend_name]) 
ImportError: You must install the python package: sqlite3
```

I have included the packages certfil, chardet, idna, requests, requests_cache and urllib3 in the execute directory..

I have it working on a python deployment with the following:

```
pip list

Package        Version
-------------- ---------
certifi        2018.4.16
chardet        3.0.4
idna           2.6
pip            10.0.1
pysqlite       2.7.0
requests       2.18.4
requests-cache 0.4.13
urllib3        1.22
```

I know it says sqlite3 which I have tried including locally but this does not work.

Comment: it says you should install the python package: sqlite3. by the way, which python are you using? python 2 or 3?

Comment: python version?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

[sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) is part of the standard library, but there are some environments where it isn't supported, for example cloud providers that use ephemeral storage. One that I'm aware of is Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

If that's the case for your environment, consider using one of the other backends instead: https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/backends.html

Current versions of requests-cache will fall back to a non-persistent in-memory cache if `sqlite3` isn't available.